# Running different R functions from different R Script files

Tags: r, function

I would like to know how to run different functions from different R script files.

For example, in `Main.R`:

```
source("Database.R")
msci_data <- getIndex() #function from Database.R

source("Positions.R")
current_positions <- getPositions() #function from Positions.R
```

I realized after running `getPositions()` method , my `msci_data` data frame gets deleted. Is there anyway I can call multiple functions from two different source files?

Thanks very much

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's going on without knowing what's in, at the least, `Positions.R`

Comment: its just that when i run source("Positions.R") the msci_data is gone...

Comment: I understand that's the **effect** you are observing from running `source("Positions.R")`, but to uncover the **cause** of that effect, it will be necessary for us to see the *contents* of Positions.R. In other words, this is not general behavior of sourcing R scripts, so it must be something in the code of Positions.R that is causing this; therefore, we cannot help you without seeing the code in Positions.R

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. i suspect that because source("Position.R") is executed, it sort of delete away the functions in source("Database.R")?

Comment: No, it does not. Not unless there is code **within** Positions.R that causes this behavior. It is **not** a general behavior of sourcing multiple R scripts. I will add a brief demonstration that sourcing multiple R scripts does not remove anything from your global environment, but no one can help you actually solve your problem without seeing your code. Please see [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If data frame(s) are being removed, look for any `rm()` calls. Some scripts begin by cleaning out environment: `rm(list=ls())`.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your reply. @Parfait is right... there is a rm() line...careless...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short demonstration that, in general, sourcing multiple R scripts will not remove anything from your global environment.

I have in a file `foo.R`:

```
foo <- function(x) x^2
```

I then have in a file `bar.R`:

```
bar <- function(x) x^3
```

Then from `main.R`, I do the following:

```
x <- 1:10
ls()
# [1] "x"

source("foo.R")
foo(x)
# [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
ls()
# [1] "foo" "x"  

source("bar.R")
bar(x)
# [1]    1    8   27   64  125  216  343  512  729 1000
ls()
# [1] "bar" "foo" "x"
```

You can see the functions all work as expected, and nothing is ever removed from the global environment. It must be that something in your `Positions.R` file is what causes this behavior, so no one can help you solve your problem without seeing your code.